# How to perform FULL JOIN, LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, left-join, querying, right-join

I am new to PostgreSQL. We have given an activity to perform FULL JOIN, LEFT JOIN, AND RIGHT JOIN. I have an answer but I am not sure if it is right. I need some help to correct me.

These are the questions and my answers.

1. Perform a FULL JOIN on staff and staff_ph TABLE WHERE region_id is 8 AND sort from the highest salary to the lowest salary.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM staff FULL JOIN staff_ph 
ON staff.id = staff_ph.id 
WHERE staff.region_id = 8 
ORDER BY staff.salary DESC;
```

2. Perform a LEFT JOIN on staff and staff_ph TABLE WHERE region_id is 8 AND sort by last_name.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM staff LEFT JOIN staff_ph 
ON staff.id = staff_ph.id 
WHERE staff.region_id = 8 
ORDER BY staff.last_name DESC;
```

3. Perform a RIGHT JOIN on staff and staff_ph TABLE WHERE region_id is 8 AND sort by gender.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM staff RIGHT JOIN staff_ph 
ON staff.id = staff_ph.id 
WHERE staff.region_id = 8 
ORDER BY staff.gender DESC;
```

Comment: Looks right at first glance, except the last two statements might need to sort `ASC`.

Comment: Oh yes, It's should be ASC. Thank you very much, sir!

Answer (score 1):

Your FULL JOIN and RIGHT JOIN don't make much sense, since you then filter out the rows where staff.region_id was fabricated as NULL.  On the other hand, it seems to be the question, not your answer, that is to blame for this.  Maybe the intention was for that condition to go in the ON, not the WHERE.